# jQuery Ajax and AddThis social bookmark application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bookmarks

I am developing a website that has an [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) Integration

Here's my situation right now,

Every time a user inputs an RSS Feed in a text input, it will display the results in the same page since I'm using an AJAX on fetching the data. Together with the result is the AddThis code that has javascripts in it.
My problem here is the AddThis button is not appearing when I started using AJAX. But before using that one, it works perfectly.

Here's the code.

```
<div id="entry-form">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Insert RSS Feed Here:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="url" id="url" style='width:300px;' /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <input type='button' name='submit' value='Submit' class='submit' />
    <div class='urlResult' style='background-color:white; width:75%;'></div>

    </div>
```

When the user clicks on the button it runs on this jQuery script:

```
jQuery('.submit').click(function() {
        if( jQuery('#url').val() == "" )
            return false;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:   "POST",
            url:    "parse.php",
            data:   "url="+jQuery('#url').val(),
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery(".urlResult").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

This is the parse.php file/code:

```
<?php
$file = $_POST['url'];

$xml = simplexml_load_file($file,'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);

foreach($xml as $key)
{

    $links = $key->item;

    for($x=0; $x<count($links); $x++) 
    { 
        echo "<pre>";
        echo $links[$x]->link;
        echo "</pre>";
?>

        <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
        <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
        <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4e6622545c73a715"></script>
        <!-- AddThis Button END -->

    <?php
    }
}           
    ?>
```

The problem here is that this code is not appearing since I started to use jquery-ajax:
This code allows the display of the addThis buttons.

```
  <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
            <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
            <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4e6622545c73a715"></script>
```

The javascript files that were embedded on my site is only the jQuery script.

Comment: I am having a similar issue where the script tag loads in the addthis__[blah].js only once, and never does it again unless you refresh the page. I'll post a solution when I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This post solved my issue -- you need to dynamically load in the script via $.getScript():
http://kb.jaxara.com/how-initialize-addthis-social-sharing-widgets-loaded-ajax